# Place an item at a fixed position in a scrolling div

Tags: html, css

I have a page full of content and `window` is scrollable, in which there is scrollable `div` where my objective is to place an icon at the very bottom of the `div`, which will be visible when someone is scrolling the `div` and will not visible after content disappears or `window` scrolls.
But I am not getting how could I achieve my objective. As making it `fixed` It get visible to whole `body` scroll.

I want that element to be fixed at the div's bottom and will not visible if the `body` scrolls
Below I am giving an example:

```css
div { height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid; 
    overflow:auto;
    position:relative;
    
    }
span {
  background : red;
  position : fixed;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>I have something</p>
    <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf  dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
    <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf  dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
    <span>this need to fixed at the botti=om and visible while scrolling the div</span>
</div>

    <p>I have something</p>
    <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf  dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
    <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf  dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
    <p>I have something</p>
    <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf  dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
    <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf  dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
```

As you can see the red strip content is visible to the whole body if I `position` it to be `fixed`. However, i just want it to be fixed at the div's  bottom and visible only when `div` scrolling.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A standardly supported way is to edit the HTML markup and add a wrapper element to both the scrollable and the *"fixed"* element - which will now have `position: absolute;` instead:

```css
#wrapper {  /* ADDED */
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

#scrollable {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapperFooter {
  background: red;
  position: absolute; /**/
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scrollable">
    <p style="border: 4px dashed #000; height: 200px;"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapperFooter">ABSOLUTELY! :)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for `sticky` position like this

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>I have something</p>
  <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
  <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
  <span>this need to fixed at the bottom and visible while scrolling the div</span>
</div>

<p>I have something</p>
<p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
<p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
<p>I have something</p>
<p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
<p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
```

Simply pay attention to [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky) as this property is not yet supported everywhere

Here is another trick using fixed position but more a hack than a generic solution.

```css
body {
  transform:translate(0,0); /* Block fixed position from scrolling*/
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top:-110px; /*this need to be calculated depending on content*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>I have something</p>
  <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
  <p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
  <span>this need to fixed at the bottom and visible while scrolling the div</span>
</div>

<p>I have something</p>
<p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
<p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
<p>I have something</p>
<p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
<p>I have something shdbfs jsdfjhs d sdfhsjdgf dsb usbsd shdshdhsdbs ds dvhsd sdshd vcsgdvshuc sd chjsdcsshdcbshudcuysdchusd cuyssdc shd cscyusdc gsdcsducsgcs uycsucs sdusdyu</p>
```

Comment: well, I got a solution using pseudo property after but that works only when the parent is static so answer worked for me after some tweak thanks :)